# Is there any way to separate APC opcode (file) cache and user cache

Tags: apc

My user cache have high change (expire/put) rate so create very high fragmentation and force too many cache flush.
Beside some time i need to flush only one of them.
Is there any method to separate or allow create many separate cache space with APC?